# C# .NET WEB API: cycling file upload location accessible and modifiable by various asynchronous HTTP requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I'm trying to create an asynchronous ASP.NET WEB API file uploader in C#, with a cycling upload location (different SMB shares that each receive an upload in turn).

The file uploading is all good and done, responding asynchronously to HTTP POST requests, but I need code like the following:

```
public class FileUploadPlaceholder
{
    private string[] uploadPathArray = new string[] { "~/import1", "~/import2", "~/import3" };
    private int uploadPathPointer = 0;
    private int uploadPathPointerMax = 2;

    public string uploadPath()
    {
        return uploadPathArray[uploadPathPointer];
    }

    public void cycleUploadPath()
    {
    //the below will be thread safe once I get further along
        if (uploadPathPointer < uploadPathPointerMax)
        {
            uploadPathPointer += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            uploadPathPointer = 0;
        }
    //the above will be thread safe once I get further along
    }

}
```

...accessible constantly by all asynchronous requests. Just one constantly-changing instance of this class would be accessible by all requests once the application was initialized. What are best practices with regards to where code like this is placed and how it is accessed by a controller like mine, a FileUploadController?

Also, feel free to criticize my code as I'm just starting out in C# and eager to know if I'm doing something unconventionally, but please provide an explanation to go with it--learner here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a solution myself by making all class methods and fields static, so we iterate through an array with a position that pertains to the class, not an instance of the class. This class can sit right next to the FileUploaderController, in the same namespace.

```
public class FileUploadPlaceholder
{
    static private string[] uploadPathArray = new string[] { "~/import1", "~/import2", "~/import3" };
    static private int uploadPathPointer = 0;
    static private int uploadPathPointerMax = 2;

    static public string uploadPath()
    {
        return uploadPathArray[uploadPathPointer];
    }

    static public void cycleUploadPath()
    {
    //the below will be thread safe once I get further along
        if (uploadPathPointer < uploadPathPointerMax)
        {
            uploadPathPointer += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            uploadPathPointer = 0;
        }
    //the above will be thread safe once I get further along
    }

}

//[Authorize]
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
{

    public async Task<List<string>> PostAsync()
    {
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            string uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(FileUploadPlaceholder.uploadPath());
[...]
```